# Asp .net Core 3.1 windows auth user impersonation to call webapi

Tags: api, asp.net-core, authentication, impersonation

I have a .net core 3.1 web app using Windows authentication. The web app needs to make requests to a .net Core 3.1 API *as the user* and that API will also need to call additional intranet services *as the user*. The app and the API are hosted on the same server and both use Windows authentication.

**What is the correct way to impersonate the current Windows auth user to make an API request?** (The app can successfully make calls to the API without impersonation, but the request will be run as the app pool user.) The two test methods in `HomeController` were cobbled together from days of scouring MS docs and SO examples but each produces a `FileLoadException` for a version `System.Net.Http` which is not referenced by the .csproj file--and it only happens when impersonation is used.

```
// impersonation in the method
public async Task<IActionResult> AskForSomethingWithImpersonationAsync()
{
    var apiBase = new Uri(configuration["Api"]);
    var response = string.Empty;
    var user = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity;

    await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(user.AccessToken, async () =>
    {
        var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache { { apiBase, "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials } };
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credentialsCache };
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = apiBase, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        response = httpClient.GetStringAsync("/api/v2/log").Result;
    });

    return Content(response);
}

// impersonation middleware
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ImpersonationFilter))]
public async Task<IActionResult> AskForSomethingFilteredAsync()
{
    var apiBase = new Uri(configuration["Api"]);
    var response = string.Empty;
    var user = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity;

    var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache { { apiBase, "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials } };
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credentialsCache };
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = apiBase, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) };
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("/api/v2/log");

    return Content(response);
}
```

Here is the impersonation filter middleware:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HBACaller.ActionFilter
{
    public class ImpersonationFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
    {
        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
            ActionExecutingContext context,
            ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            var user = (WindowsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity;

            await WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(user.AccessToken, async () =>
            {
                await next();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error I see in my web browser's network response tab:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: 
File name: 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
```

As far as I can tell, that version is not referenced anywhere. The .csproj has this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Security.Principal" Version="4.3.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When this code is published to a test IIS server instead of running local through Visual Studio, there is an additional message tacked on to the end of the exception:
`Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.`

If it helps it helps to see the complete (failing) project, here's the repo: https://github.com/cestarte/core_impersonate_winauth_user

Comment: You have included the wrong dll's. If you want to deal with windows authentication, you need the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate" package. To call the other endpoint I would recommend to use the "RestSharp" package.